# How access custom textbox name in Laravel using validation 'unique'?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel

I have a simple question. In my form I am creating a validation process that check the username in the database record if existed or not.

My problem is the Laravel validation is using the textbox name as a column name in it's query.
In my table I have these columns:

username,
lastname,
firstname,
password

And in my textboxes I have this:

admin_username,
admin_lastname,
admin_firstname,
admin_password

So I got this error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin_username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `administrators` where `admin_username` = flaxadmin123)
```

This is the result of my validation:

```
'admin_username'    =>  'required|min:5|max:15|unique:administrators',
```

How to change the admin_username to username when validating or querying?

Comment: hmm so in laravel there's no function like the one I ask? :(

Comment: That can use custom textbox name when querying or validating. Because as I have said. In validating the Laravel is using the textbox name for querying in the database. In order for me to create a validation that will check the username if exists or not. The textbox name in my form should be the same as the column name in database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify custom column name in the validation.

```
'admin_username'    =>  'required|min:5|max:15|unique:administrators,username',
```

This will use the **username** column instead of **admin_username**